# autohotkey simultaneous keystrokes with repeats

Tags: macros, autohotkey, code, keystrokes

*I got this right now*

---

settitlematchmode,3

SetKeyDelay, 350

^o::

$stop := 0

Loop,

{

```
controlsend,,{a 30},ahk_pid 12144
controlsend,,{a 30}{s 30},ahk_pid 12144
controlsend,,{s 30},ahk_pid 12144
controlsend,,{s 30}{d 30},ahk_pid 12144
controlsend,,{d 30},ahk_pid 12144
controlsend,,{d 30}{w 30},ahk_pid 12144
controlsend,,{w 30},ahk_pid 12144
controlsend,,{w 30}{a 30},ahk_pid 12144
controlsend,,{w 30},ahk_pid 12144
controlsend,,{w 30}{d 30},ahk_pid 12144
controlsend,,{d 30},ahk_pid 12144
controlsend,,{d 30}{s 30},ahk_pid 12144
controlsend,,{s 30},ahk_pid 12144
controlsend,,{s 30}{a 30},ahk_pid 12144
if ($stop)
{
  return
}
```

}

^p:: $stop := 1

---

controlsend,,{a 30}{s 30} sends 30 times "a" and then 30 times "s" but I want 30 times "as"

Single keystroke with 30 repeats works without problems but simultaneous keystrokes doesn't work simultaneously. Instead it works sequentially. Can you help with that?

Comment: send {as} doesn't work?

Comment: nope it doesn't :(

Comment: Oh sorry. Two ways I think that may help. send {a}{s}; or mystr:="as"; send %mystr%;

Comment: Try adding a variable and setting it to equal "as"? Something like string = as. `controlsend,,%string%, ahk_pid 12144`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...but I want 30 times "as"

Two ways I think that may help.

```
send {a}{s} ; 
            ;  or 
mystr:="as" ;  set a string value
send %mystr%; send string
```

Loops:

```
mystr:="as" ;  set a string value
Loop, 30
{
    send %mystr%; send string 
}
```

Comment: That helped. Now at least it sends "asasas" not "aaasss". But still there is delay between "a" and "s". They do not register simultaneously. I'll try to make it work like this. Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you trying to use "as" as a combination input like SHIFT-S for example? If all you want is an input of "as", then using the string input method of mystring:="as" will register the String as a single input of memory I should think. What is the nature of the "as", as you want for it?

Comment: I wanted it to register a and s without delay between them and sleep for 1000 and register as again. Your code worked with minor adjustment for my situation. Thx alot.

Comment: Oh, great. Glad it worked out.